# Environment settings needed for learning " *Computer Systems:A Programmer's Perspective*"

Tags: c, compiler-optimization, cpu-architecture

I am reading the book *Computer Systems: A Programmer's Perspective*, and I am trying to execute the code it provides on my Macbook Pro with Intel Core i7.

But some code just does not run exactly as the book suggests.

This C example is supposed to demonstrate that the same float will differ when stored in memory from when it's stored in the register.

```
#include<stdio.h>

double recip( int denom )
{
  return 1.0/(double) denom;
}

void do_nothing(){} /* to  clear the register */

void fcomp( int denom)
{
  double r1, r2;
  int t1, t2;

  r1 = recip(denom); /* stored in memory */
  r2 = recip(denom); /* stored in register */
  t1 = r1 == r2;     /* Compares register to memory */
  do_nothing();      /* Forces register save to memory */
  t2 = r1 == r2;     /* Compares memory to memory */
  printf("test1 t1: r1 %f %c= r2 %f\n", r1, t1 ? '=' : '!', r2);
  printf("test1 t1: r2 %f %c= r2 %f\n", r1, t2 ? '=' : '!', r2);
}

main(){
  int demon = 10;
  fcomp(demon);
}
```

Compared with the gcc with "O2" option, the result, suggested by the book, should be:

```
test1 t1: r1 0.100000 != r2 0.100000
test2 t1: r1 0.100000 == r2 0.100000
```

However, I got two "=="s and wonder why. Any suggestion on the environment settings for the book? Thanks a lot.

Comment: You should keep the book on a dry desktop out of direct sunlight...

Comment: Note that any halfway-decent compiler can prove that the call to `do_nothing()` does nothing, and simply not emit any code for it. Said compiler can also reliably prove, incidentally, that `r1` and `r2` should have the same value, and optimize your assignments away, and optimize the ternary operator in the `printf()` calls down to a straight `'='`. Additionally, I see nothing in the code that says anything about registers, so any assumption being made about values stored in registers is completely unwarranted.

Comment: Something is very wrong here. The book was written by Randal Bryant who is a well known guy. Some of the book is online. Are you sure your code snippet is what's in the book? What's the chapter, section and page?

Comment: @ElchononEdelson:Thanks, the book suggests it is run on the IA32 processor,compiled and assembled by unknown version of gcc. The author might want to demonstrate the architect of X86, or some how. As the question title suggests, I would like to know whether it is ok that I could learn how x86 works through the book with my pro. Thanks again;)

Comment: @CharlieBurns:Thanks, I am reading a hard copy of the book. And I guess it is Edition 1, for there is no mentioning about the Edition.The Code is in Section 2.4.6 Float Point in C. It is located in the place before the Aside:Why should we be concerned.... I will try to see whether there is a copy on line. And I try to download a copy of the second edition in [bookfi](http://en.bookfi.org), the parts has been deleted from the book. I guess, it is indeed the problem,Thanks again

Comment: The source code and the comments in the source code, and the expected results make no sense whatsoever. I'm surprised it made it into the first edition but it is good it is gone from the second edition. Given the author, I would think it would be a good book to learn from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The example in the book aims (most likely) at the particular properties of the x87 FPU in Intel CPUs: The main property of this FPU type is that it provides only registers with a (visible) 80 Bit precision. So 32 or 64 bit floats are converted into 80 bit floats when loaded into an FPU register. Further, normally arithmetic operations are carried out with full precision, so if a value is kept in a FPU register for later use, it is not rounded to 32 or 64 bit as it is done for a value which is copied into memory and then loaded back later on. Due to this it makes a difference if a value is kept in a register or not.

However, Mac OS X (which I suppose you are using on a Macbook) does not make use of the x87 FPU, it uses the SSE unit: SSE provides 32 and 64 bit floating point register and operations so it makes no difference if a value is kept in a register or stored in memory regarding its precision. The result is always rounded after each operation. This applies normally to 64 bit exectubles on windows and Linux as well.

On e.g. 32 bit, Linux or Windows the situation is different. The use of the x87 or SSE unit depends on the enviroment, often the x87 FPU is used because 32 Bit machines might not support the needed SSE2 instructions, though the last CPUs without SSE2 were built approximately 10 years ago.

Comment: +1 This is a great explanation of the behavior I empirically found for my [non-answer answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19308894/environment-settings-needed-for-learning-computer-systemsa-programmers-pers/19323829#19323829)

Answer (score 0):

Not much of an answer, but I researched this a little bit.  I found this fcomp.c http://csapp.cs.cmu.edu/public/1e/ics/code/data/fcomp.c, which looks like it is probably from the same example from your book, but your version is just contains the first test.  Anyway I played with various different gcc versions and -m32 vs -m64 and found that test1 (the same as your test) always comes up equal, at least for i386 and x86_64.

However there is one test (test2) which seems to exhibit architecture-dependent behavior:

```
void test2(int denom)
{
  double r1;
  int t1;
  r1 = recip(denom);             /* Default: register, Forced store: memory */
  t1 = r1 == 1.0/(double) denom; /* Compares register or memory to register */
  printf("test2 t1: r1 %f %c= 1.0/10.0\n", r1, t1 ? '=' : '!');  
  printf("A long double on this machine requires %d bytes\n", sizeof(long double));
}
```

(test2() is called with a demon of 10)

When compiling with `gcc -m64 -o fcomp fcomp.c` I get this output:

```
test2 t1: r1 0.100000 == 1.0/10.0
A long double on this machine requires 16 bytes
```

Whereas when compiling with `gcc -m32 -o fcomp fcomp.c` I get this output:

```
test2 t1: r1 0.100000 != 1.0/10.0
A long double on this machine requires 12 bytes
```

For the record, I got these results with both gcc 3.4.6 and 4.1.2.

All of the other tests come up equal, regardless of what compiler/arch I use.

Comment: I forgot to play with -O options.  All tests pass for x86_64, regardless of -O option.  However for i386, with -O0 test2 fails; with -O1 test4 t1 and t2 fail and with -O2 all tests pass.